# SQL1159 Initialization error with DB2 .NET Data Provider, reason code 10, tokens 0.0.0, 8.1.18

Tags: asp.net, db2, asmx

I am trying to connect the db2 Server from my asmx and asp.net(IIS) but I am getting the below error . I have given full access to network Service for IBM.Data.DB.dll

```
{System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: SQL1159  Initialization error with DB2 .NET Data Provider, reason code 10, tokens 0.0.0, 8.1.18
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.d()
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool..ctor()
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection..ctor(String connectionString)
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the database outside the .Net code, e.g. with the DB2 command line processor? Did you perform the troubleshooting steps suggested by the [error description in the manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01159n.html)?

Comment: @mustaccio I have tried connecting through odbcad in the systemwow64 where the connection is establishing successfully. Don't know why in the asp.net it is not getting connected as I am doing migration of the code from the windows Server 2003 to windows Server 2016 hope it is problem related to Data Client